# Why is the loop not working? if & C function

Tags: r

```r
data_base<- c("www.url1.com","www.url2.com","www.url3.com")
data1<-c("www.url4.com","www.url5.com","www.url2.com")

lapply(data1,function(x){if(is.element(x, data_base)==F){
                               data_base<-c(data_base,x)}else{NULL}})
```

I want to test each element in the "data1" vector and, if it doesn't match any of the ones that already exist in "data_base", add it to "data_base".It's not adding, even though the condition is true
.

Comment: What is `data_base`.  Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: I think you already got a good answer from @GeorgeSavva with `union`, but if you *really* want to use the `lapply` solution from your question, you'll have to use `data_base <<- c(data_base, x)` to assign to the parent environment.

Comment: You have a scope problem as well, and I do not encourage you to fix it in the literal/direct method (i.e., `<<-`). The problem is that your assignment to `data_base` inside of `lapply` is kept there, it is not overriding the variable in your global environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is:

```
data_base <- union( data_base , data1 )
```

so

```
data_base<- c("www.url1.com","www.url2.com","www.url3.com")
data1<-c("www.url4.com","www.url5.com","www.url2.com")

data_base <- union(data_base, data1)

> data_base
[1] "www.url1.com" "www.url2.com" "www.url3.com" "www.url4.com" "www.url5.com"
```

But to directly answer your question, you are only updating `data_base` within the environment created by the function in `lapply`.  You would need to return it or assign it using `<<-` (but don't do that) to get the behaviour you expected.

Comment: +1 for the *"don't do that"*, I so discourage the use of `<<-`, `assign`, and `get` in all but very specific situations ... and this is not one of them.

Comment: why "<< -" is not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to use loops, you can try the `for` loop like below

```
for (x in data1) {
  if (!is.element(x,data_base)) {
    data_base <- c(data_base,x)
  }
}
```

- If you want to use `*apply` functions, you can try `sapply`

```
data_base <- na.omit(c(data_base,sapply(data1,function(x) ifelse(!is.element(x, data_base),x,NA),USE.NAMES = FALSE)))
```

Both solutions will give you

```
> data_base
[1] "www.url1.com" "www.url2.com" "www.url3.com"
[4] "www.url4.com" "www.url5.com"
```